# MySQL how to insert one value without affecting other values

Tags: mysql, insert

In my table "accounts" I have four columns like

*user, pass, column1, column2*
I need to insert value into column2, where user='special_user_value'.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE accounts
SET    column2 = 'New Value'
WHERE  user = 'special_user_value';
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't "insert values" into a column. You insert a *row*, that has a value for all the columns you specified in the table creation; Just like a real table, or excel sheet for that matter.

If you need to *change* a column value for a specific row, you can use [`UPDATE`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp):

`UPDATE table_name SET column2='new value' WHERE user='special_user_value'`

This is a really basic example. If you follow the link I provided for [`UPDATE`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp), you may learn more about changing table values for a specific row.

If are you looking for actually inserting a new row with a specific value for that column, there's [`INSERT INTO`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) you could follow to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Use update Query like:

```
Update table_nm set field1=value1,  Field2=value2 Where condition;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Accounts SET column2='NewValue' WHERE user='special_user_value'
```